# java.lang.NumberFormatException error in Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium

I'm newcomer to java selenium. I'm trying to automate and I have failed. I need to verify the unit price of the product I added to the cart and the price that will occur when I add 1 more of the same product, but I get the error "Exception in thread"main" java.lang.NumberFormatException".

That's my code:

```
//check the amount to be paid to the products
String unitPrice = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='m-basket-card__price m-basket-card__price--main']")).getText();
System.out.println("single price of the product= " + unitPrice);
String totalPrice = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//sub[@class='js-card-price']")).getText();
System.out.println("total price of the cart = " + totalPrice);
Assert.assertEquals(totalPrice, Integer.parseInt(unitPrice * 2));
```

I get the error on the last line.

I tried to multiply the price of the product by 2 to verify the price of 2 of the same product. I converted string to int value. But it gave an "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException" error.

Comment: are you aware that you try to multiply a `String` by 2 and then parse it to an `Integer`?

Comment: what should i do to fix this problem?

Comment: can you try with Integer.parseInt(unitPrice)*2

Comment: I'm not sure that the shift of the `)` will fix the exception, what does it print out for the "single price of the product= "?

Comment: sadly negative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to convert the `totalPrice` to int and also multiply the `unitPrice` as below:

```
Assert.assertEquals(Integer.parseInt(totalPrice),Integer.parseInt(unitPrice)*2);
```

If `unitPrice` and `totalPrice` return float:

```
Assert.assertEquals(Float.parseFloat(totalPrice),Float.parseFloat(unitPrice)*2);
```

Comment: unfortunately it gives the same error again

Comment: It works fine for me, what is the value of unitPrice and totalPrice?

Comment: unitPrice is 29.999 and totalPrice is 59.998

Comment: Those are float values. So, as I already mentioned in the answer, use -   Assert.assertEquals(Float.parseFloat(totalPrice),Float.parseFloat(unitPrice)*2);  You are trying to convert those values to int, that's why you are getting the same error.

Comment: There was an error in the xpaths I got. I fixed them and it worked thanks to the code you wrote. Thank you so much my friend.